# Categorical RNN model building heuristics - InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, layer

I am trying to train a recurrent network which will make a categorical prediction in one of three categories. I am trying to adapt some previous code which was working for a prediction between two categories. To do this, I just changed the last Dense() layer to have a shape of 3, rather than 2, and leaving everything else essentially the same.

However, when I run the code below I am getting the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of -9223372036854775808 which is outside the valid
range of [0, 3).  Label values:
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 -9223372036854775808 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

I don't really understand where these numbers are coming from and I would really appreciate if anyone might be able to explain them? In particular, I haven't been able to find out what the warning means by 'label values'.

Generally, I don't think there are many in-depth articles to be found on stackoverflow or elsewhere about how to design networks that are designed for relative beginners- I am new to using Keras, but my background is in mathematics, so tutorials which skip over the maths of what is going on in layers I haven't found particularly useful. If someone could point me towards a good source for layer design that has a more mathematical approach that would be of enormous benefit?

Additionally, all the input data was normalised, though one of the categories was between [-1,1], rather than [0,1]; I can't see why this would be a problem but perhaps it is.

```
def Network(IN, OUT, TIME_PERIOD, EPOCHS, BATCH_SIZE, LTSM_SHAPE):

    length = len(OUT)
    train_x = IN[:int(0.9 * length)]
    validation_x = IN[int(0.9 * length):]
    train_y = OUT[:int(0.9 * length)]
    validation_y = OUT[int(0.9 * length):]

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(LTSM_SHAPE, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())  

    model.add(LSTM(LTSM_SHAPE, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(LSTM(LTSM_SHAPE, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

    train_y = np.asarray(train_y)
    validation_y = np.asarray(validation_y)
    history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y))
    print('\nhistory dict:', history.history)

    # Score model
    score = model.evaluate(validation_x, validation_y, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
    # Save model
    model.save(f"models/{NAME}")

EPOCHS, BATCH_SIZE, LTSM_SHAPE = 15, 32, 128

Network(x, Y, 3, EPOCHS, BATCH_SIZE, LTSM_SHAPE)
```

Comment: i'm unfamiliar with this error but have you tried doing what it said? your targets should be between 0 and 3. a dense layer of 1 after a softmax is a weird choice. what kind of task is this?

Comment: I get the same error reference if the dense layer of 1 you refer to is removed, but it becomes: `InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (loss/dense_34_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [32 1] [y (loss/dense_34_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [32 3]
  [[node loss/dense_34_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert (defined at <ipython-input-705-4d65fd5d8e6a>:30) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_153036]

Function call stack:
distributed_function `

Comment: The task is to make the categorical prediction for the next series in the time series data, given the last 3 time instances' data